# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError on Heroku with Google Apps and Rails 3 Inconstant Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, google-apps

I have been attempting to set up my rails application on heroku with automated mailings using ActionMailer. My setup for the mail initialization is as follows: Note that the domain and usernames are dummies.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "domain.edu",
  :user_name            => "name@wesleyan.edu",
  :password             => ENV['EMAIL_PASS'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

The odd thing is, when I try to send mail with one account, I get no issues, then when I try with another, I get the error. I never went through any authentication process with either. Both reports are as follows:

Success:

```
2013-06-12T00:59:34.801877+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to recipient@domainn.edu (2464ms)
2013-06-12T00:59:34.804391+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://test.herokuapp.com/
2013-06-12T00:59:34.806552+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 3394ms (ActiveRecord: 289.6ms)
```

Failure:

```
2013-06-12T01:29:25.124493+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered agreement_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb (23.7ms)
2013-06-12T01:29:26.079394+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/agreements_controller.rb:106:in `block in create'
2013-06-12T01:29:26.079394+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-06-12T01:29:26.078426+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to madelman@wesleyan.edu (929ms)
2013-06-12T01:29:26.078426+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1137ms
2013-06-12T01:29:26.079394+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-12T01:29:26.079394+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
```

Any thoughts about why I would get this discrepancy? Thanks so much.

Comment: my first idea would be to try and use a normal smtp client to ensure that the account that you are having trouble with is sending messages correctly - I don't recall if you have to configure a Google account to be able to use SMTP? Also, could this account have Google 2 factor authentication setup and you would need to use an application specific password?

Comment: What would a normal smtp client be? I am beginning to think this is the issue, but it's odd that two email addresses from the same domain would have different properties.

Comment: something like Mail.app, outlook (shudder) etc.

Comment: Yeah. It appears that I can't get the second address working on any smtp client. Any thoughts on how to solve this? I can't find any difference in the settings of the two accounts. I guess this is a new question at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that the second email address wasn't a real address at all, but an alias, so I could never get to the real password. I contacted my administrator, and they are fixing the problem.